# Failing to load class definition from jar

Tags: java, applet, securitymanager, appletviewer

I ran across an issue when attempting to port an application over to `JApplet` so it can run on a browser.

**Program Contents:**

1. Jar file. Contains my `CustomClassLoader` implementation. Stored on website.
2. Content directory. Filled with compiled classes. Stored on the users computer.

**Issue:**

I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` when attempting to load .class files in the content directory with my `CustomClassLoader`.

The error, although unattainable, relates back to a class inside the jar. The class is abstract. All the .class files in the content directory extend this class and fill all the required methods. Upon loading these classes, the error is thrown. The program, when ran normally `java -jar file.jar`, works perfectly fine.

This makes me believe it has to do with the classpath.

**Security Setup:**

I am running the applet through the `appletviewer` command like so:

```
 appletviewer -J-Djava.security.policy=policy file.html
```

In the same directory is my policy file:

```
grant {
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getenv.APPDATA";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read, write, delete, execute";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "exitVM";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.name", "read";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader";
};
```

As far as I know, no other security exceptions are being thrown. The applet is signed.

**HTML File Used To Load Applet:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <object width="1000" height="600" classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
            codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/autodl/jinstall-1_4-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,4,0,0">
            <param name="archive" value="file.jar"/>
            <param name="code" value="package.to.Boot"/>
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help towards fixing this problem is greatly appreciated.

**CustomClassLoader.java:**

```
package org.obicere.cc.methods;

import java.io.File;

public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    //...
    private Class<?> loadClass(final File file) {
        try {
            final byte[] data = IOUtils.readData(file);
            return super.defineClass(file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length() - 6), data, 0, data.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Example Runner: CanReachRunner.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Random;

import org.obicere.cc.executor.Result;
import org.obicere.cc.tasks.projects.Runner;

public class CanReachRunner extends Runner {

    @Override
    public Result[] getResults(Class<?> clazz) {
        try {
            final Method method = clazz.getMethod("canReach", int.class, int.class, int.class);
            final Random ran = new Random();
            final Result[] results = new Result[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                final int small = ran.nextInt(5) + 5;
                final int large = ran.nextInt(5);
                final int goal = (small + large * 5) + 5 + ran.nextInt(6);
                results[i] = new Result(method.invoke(clazz.newInstance(), small, large, goal), (goal <= small + large * 5) && goal % 5 <= small, small, large, goal);
            }
            return results;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result[] {};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might give a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886565/export-java-applet-to-jar/17887205#17887205

Comment: I have 2 boot classes. One for jar access, manifest links to this one. The other for applet access, HTML links to this one.

Comment: Does any of you .java files have a main Method?

Comment: @NiteshVerma Yes. I do not see the connection between the two, when it loads perfectly fine. It just can't function properly.

Comment: Could you care to share some more code

Comment: @NiteshVerma what would you want to see?

Comment: The contenst of the jar file: CustomClassLoader and the content directory comppiled classes

Comment: @NiteshVerma I have shown what I am willing to show. I doubt the answer lies in any other place, considering it works when not ran as an applet. Only then, does it fail.

Comment: clould the problem be inside the init() method (probale, not sure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the class loader. The first is that the `loadClass` method uses an argument of a `String` rather than a `File`, the string being the name of the class to load. This is because the class to load might not be in a file, it might be on a network connection, and anyway the JVM doesn't know how to find the file. The second is that it is bad practice to override `loadClass`, because if you do, it interferes with the default behavior, which first tries to load classes the normal way, and only resorts to calling the `findClass` method if that doesn't work. So, you should override `findClass` instead of `defineClass`. Here's the updated code:

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private Class<?> findClass(String class) {
        try {
            File contentDir = ...; // You have to fill this in with the location of the content dir
            final byte[] data = IOUtils.readData(new File(contentDir, class + ".class");
            return defineClass(class, data, 0, data.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You must find the content directory somehow and use that to initialize `contentDir`.

The reason this works when run as a jar is cause it is then capable of loading the classes without needing a custom class loader.

Comment: It works perfectly fine as an executable jar, but not when ran as an applet. The `file` argument already has the `contentDir` appended and the `.class` appended (explains the substring). The classes I am also trying to load are not added in the classpath, which is why I just resort to defining them, instead of trying to load them. I am almost sure the problem lies within the security manager.

Comment: If you read that last comment I just deleted, you can ignore it. I actually found a work-around and may be coming to a solution soon. You just reminded me of something.